# Django shell doesn't respect cache configuration

Tags: python, django, caching, django-cache, django-caching

In my settings.py I have:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'ws_cache_table',
        'TIMEOUT': '3000000',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 10000000
        }
    }
}
```

But if I do this in `python manage.py shell`:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
print type(cache)
```

I'm getting:

```
django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache
```

Why!???
Now I can't clear my cache...

To prove my configuration is corect I can do:

```
from django.conf import settings
conf = settings.CACHES.get('default', None)
```

And I'm getting:

```
{'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
 'LOCATION': 'ws_cache_table',
 'OPTIONS': {'MAX_ENTRIES': 10000000},
 'TIMEOUT': '3000000'}
```

It looks like `get_cache` method is called before CACHES is defined...

Comment: Possibly you are accessing the `django.core.cache.cache` from code that is reachable in settings?

Comment: which Django version ?

Comment: Are you sure no other 'local' settings is replacing the `CACHES` setting? If you manually call `django.core.cache.get_cache('default')`, what do you obtain?

Comment: @kroolik - I don't understand, can you explain?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - 1.4

Comment: Do you import or use any code in your settings files that directly or indirectly uses or imports `django.core.cache`?

Comment: What i mean is, do you do something like `from myproj.myapp.module import MyName`, and by any chance `module` imports something that imports `django.core.cache`.

Comment: @kroolik - I see your point and you are right - i had this in my settings and this caused the problem. But this has only uncovered the real problem have and the reason I was playing witm my settings and cache, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024127/django-cant-clear-databse-cache-on-oracle-backend

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should keep in mind that your `local_settings.py` would overwrite the `settings.py`.

Then you should watch out what cache daemon as backend is running, as there are different ones and depending what you run you need the respective specified option.

e.g. for memcached the local_settings.py would read:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211'
        'CACHE_TIME': '3600',
    }
}
```

whereas for locmem:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211'
        'TIMEOUT': 3600'
    }
}
```