# Django can't clear database cache on Oracle backend

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle, django-cache

I have one row in my oracle cache table. I'm trying to clear it using standard django way:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear()
```

But it doesn't work! The row is still in my cache table.

So I run `python manage.py sell` and put some code from `DatabaseCache.clear()` method:

```
from django.db import connections
table = connections['cache'].ops.quote_name('ws_cache_table')
cursor = connections['cache'].cursor()
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM %s' % table)
```

But it doesn't work either...

I don't get any exceptions thrown, my 'cache' connection is configured correctly in `settings.py`.

When I open SQL Developer and put

```
DELETE FROM ws_cache_table
```

Table gets truncated correctly.

On the other hand, when I add:

```
connections['cache'].commit()
```

I get exception `django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management` thrown but the table is truncated now.

The question is: what should I do to get my table truncated but without throwing exception?

Is this a bug in django `DatabaseCache.clear()` method?

I'm using django 1.4.

Comment: Do you have `django-debug-toolbar`? Maybe you can run `./manage.py debugsqlshell` and run the same commands to see the SQL output.

Comment: No surprisingly the output is 'DELETE FROM ws_cache_table' ;)

Comment: Ok, that was expected. Try using `commit_unless_managed()` instead of `commit()`. (just a guess based on your exception)